# Angular 6 - Scroll to top when a modal is shown

Tags: jquery, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am using **Angular 6** to build a web application and I am using **Bootstrap 3** for my styles. I am **not** using any particular Angular frameworks for Bootstrap like [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) or [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home), I just have CDN references to Bootstrap 3 within my index.html.

Now I am showing modals, which is great. However, I would like to trigger some code when every modal is shown.

At the moment, I have the following code in a `confirm.component.ts` file:

```
$('#confirmModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  console.log('Modal is shown...');
});
```

This works perfectly, it prints to the console when this modal is shown. However, if I add the code below to my `app.component.ts` file it does not trigger when a modal is shown. I was hoping that `app.component.ts` would act as a global component for my whole project.

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  console.log('Modal is shown...');
});
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have a single piece of code which is triggered whenever **any** modal is shown. I could duplicate the code I used in my first sample onto every modal in my web application but ideally, this is something I would like to avoid.

Does anyone know if this is possible in an Angular application?

Comment: Use fragment identifier.

Comment: take a look at this, If you are looking just for a simple message. This might work. http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/06/25/angular-6-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject

Answer (score 0):

This definitely possible with Angular.

You can create separate component for Modal, you bind input & output event with create component. Then this component can be reused within other components.

You can use this tutorial for in-depth knowledge : https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/components/overview/